# Cordova iOS 13 pick up video empty file content

Tags: ios, cordova, ios13

**Bug Report**

Hello everyone,

I'm in trouble since few days now. I know that many responses were written about a similar issue but I think that mine is different.
I'm using `Cordova` to create an application and I need to upload photos and videos.
The upload is ok and make with the help of Ajax.
Before to upload i create a formData and append all of my files(this part is ok to)
This is good on android and iOS behind 13

**strong text For iOS 13 it's another deal**

When the user pick up photo the file (on JS side) is generated with success. When i try to pick up video there is an error, the file is completely empty and is length is at 0.
I tried to see the file content with JSON stringily and the result for the video is this : {}
I don't know why I can read photo but not video :/

I really need help.

**Thanks in advance !**

Comment: It is because the videos have new `.trim` string in their filename. And I suppose, that Cordova couldn't process file with this name. Consider renaming.
Please, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59063961/ios-13-adds-trim-prefix-to-files-selected-from-uiimagepickcontroller/59240522#59240522)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205720/video-transcoding-problem-in-ionic-with-ios-13-0) fix your issue?